# Split a list at certain values without omission

Tags: list-manipulation

This sounds simple and very likely a duplicate but I couldn't find an answer. Is there a quick functional way to split a list at certain values (multiple locations) while keeping those values in the subsists?

As an example:

```
seq1 = Range[10];
splitat1 = {1};
SequenceSplit[seq1, splitat1]
```

results in:

> {{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}

Here is my first problem, 1 is missing. Maybe I should be using a different method than `SequenceSplit`? Furthermore, what if I want to split at several locations? I tried this:

```
splitat2 = {{1}, {6}};
FlattenAt[SequenceSplit[seq1, #] & /@ splitat2, 1]
```

but obviously I am doing it wrong as I am splitting the list several times and then they repeat:

> {{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {7, 8, 9, 10}}}

How would I get this result?

> {{1},{2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10}}

Now having it split at the first element is a little bit harder probably, so even if there is chance splitting at {2,6} results in either

> {{1,2},{3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10}}

or

> {{1},{2, 3, 4, 5}, {6,7, 8, 9, 10}}

that would still solve my problem yet in a different way.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark thanks, I couldn't get that to work yet. The criteria basically the split points are given as a list of members.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Split`:

```
Split[seq1, # != splitat1[[1]] &]
```

> ```
> {{1}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}
> ```

```
Split[seq1, # != 5 &]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}
> ```

```
Split[seq1, ! MatchQ[2 | 6] @ # &]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10}}
> ```

```
Split[seq1, Nor[# == 2, # == 6] &]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10}}
> ```

Comment: These are very promising, thanks! Is there a way I can construct the pattern to pass the split points as another list? let's say `splitat= {2,5,7,9}`? maybe `MemberQ`?

Comment: `!MemberQ[{2,5,7,9},#]&`  or `!MatchQ[Alternatives@@{2,5,7,9}]@#&` should work.

Comment: This a great, thanks a lot! `Split[seq1, ! MemberQ[splitat, #] &]` works beautifully.

Answer (score 4):

```
list = Range[10];
```

**1.**

Using `TakeList` and `Splice` (new in 12.1)

```
p = {6};

TakeList[list, {First @ p, Splice @ Differences @ p, All}]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10}}

```
p = {2, 6};

TakeList[list, {First @ p, Splice @ Differences @ p, All}]
```

> {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10}}

**2.**

For a single split we can use `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
SequenceSplit[list, p : {a___, 6} :> p]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10}}

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have a list of numbers from 1-20 and you want to split it in `sections` given as follows:

```
alist = Range[20]
sections = {1, 5, 4, 6}
```

Use `FoldPairList`

```
FoldPairList[TakeDrop, alist, sections]
```

> {{1}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}}

---

If you want the remaining part of the list as well:

```
FoldPairList[TakeDrop, alist, {Splice[sections], 
  Length@alist - Total@sections}]
```

> ```
> {{1}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}, {17, 
>   18, 19, 20}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks, this solution is nice too. I just converted my split element list to the sections as you have defined by `sections = Prepend[Differences[splitat], First@splitat]` and got the same results as @kglr solution.