# Find all the ways to split a list into sets of lists of given length

Tags: list-manipulation

**NOTE**

I'm sorry, my question was not clear. I want to know all the ways to split a list with a given length simply, **rather than split a cyclic substitution**.
If a given list has length $N$ and the rule is ${m, n, p, ...}$, we should get a list of length ${}_{N} C_{m} {}_{N-m} C_{n} {}_{N-m-n} C_{p} \dots = \frac{N!}{m! n! p! \cdots}$ if all elements of $N$ are independent.

Other examples:
`Length@partitionList[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}, {2, 2, 4}]`
returns $420 = \frac{8!}{2! 2! 4!}$

`Length@partitionList[{a, b, b, c, d, e, e, f}, {2, 2, 4}]`
returns 173

---

**Question**

I want to split a given list into sets of lists, whose lengths are given.
For example, this means if we split a list `{a, b, c, d}` (length 4) to two lists with length `{1, 3}` (the sum of lengths should be 4), we obtain

```
{{{a}, {b, c, d}}, {{b}, {c, d, a}}, {{c}, {d, e, a}}, {{d}, {e, a, b}}
```

(here, we don't care about ordering for elements in each sublist).

To achieve this, I prepared the following function:

```Mathematica
partitionList[l_List, p_List] := 
DeleteDuplicates@(Module[{$tmp, $deleteList, $lastchoose, 
    l2 = Range[Length@l]},
   $tmp = Subsets[l2, {p[[1]]}];
   $deleteList = Flatten /@ $tmp;
   If[Length@p > 1,
    Do[
     $lastchoose = 
      Table[Subsets[
        Delete[l2, {#} & /@ $deleteList[[$j]]], {p[[$i]]}], {$j, 
        Length@$deleteList}];
     $tmp = 
      Replace[Flatten[
        Tuples /@ Transpose[{{#} & /@ $tmp, $lastchoose}], 1], 
       x_ /; Depth@x > 2 :> Sequence @@ x, {2} ];
     $deleteList = Flatten /@ $tmp;
     , {$i, 2, Length@p}]
    ];
   Map[l[[#]] &, $tmp, {2}]
   ]
  )
```

Here, the argument $l$ is a list which we want to split, and $p$ is a list of lengths of sublists.
In the previous example, $l$ is `{a, b, c, d}` and $p$ is `{1, 3}`.

However, since it is based on procedural programming, I believe there are more efficient ways.
Could you please suggest such a method?

Comment: Try: `Select[Subsets[
  Subsets[{a, b, c, d}]], (! MemberQ[#, {}] && 
    Length[Flatten@#] == 4) &]`

Comment: Perhaps [263461](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263459/dividing-a-list-into-n-non-overlapping-pieces/263461#263461)  has a few pointers. Also please take a look at an answer I just [wrote](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264586/split-a-list-at-certain-values-without-omission).

Comment: @DanielHuber Thank you! but based on your method we have to pick some lists which satisfy the given condition..

Comment: does the input list have duplicates?

Comment: @kglr It may do.

Comment: So far, @kglr's solution works, and works well for `n<12`. For high `n` (>=13) it takes a very long time and memory (>10 Gb), could be more as I aborted. @user1066's answer contains duplicates. I'm also working on a solution but I'm getting sleepy and not sure if I could provide better solution than kglr's. IMHO loop construction can actually be faster in this case.

Answer (score 4):

```
kSP = ResourceFunction["KSetPartitions"];

partitionLst[a_, p_] := Select[Sort@Map[Length] @ # == Sort @ p &][
    DeleteDuplicates @ Sort @ kSP[a, Length @ p]]


partitionLst[{a, b, c, d}, {1, 3}]
```

> ```
> {{{a}, {b, c, d}}, {{a, b, c}, {d}}, {{a, b, d}, {c}}, {{a, c, d}, {b}}}
> ```

```
partitionLst[{a, b, c, d}, {2, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{a, c}, {b, d}}, {{a, d}, {b, c}}}
> ```

Comment: It will have duplicates.

Comment: Thank you @ShinKim; good point.

Comment: My function `partitionList` and your suggestion `partitionLst` do actually different results, for example `Length@partitionList[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, {1, 2, 3}] `$\neq$ `Length@partitionLst[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, {1, 2, 3}]`.

Comment: @kglr I am now imagining that we could combine your Split[] method in your other question just now with Permutation[].

Comment: @Keyspire, please see the updated version.

Comment: @kglr Sorry for my unclear explanation, but your function does not work correctly. Indeed, as in my "NOTE" section, I want to obtain $N!/(m! n! p! \cdots)$ lists because I don't care about ordering of elements in each sublist (here sublists mean lists at level 2 like {a} or {b, c, d}) but do about that of each sublist.

Comment: @kglr An example: `Range[12], {3, 1, 4, 2, 2}` case.

Comment: @Keyspire That formula doesn't work if $p$ has a repeating index. For example `{a,b,c,d}` having `{1,1,1,1}` (formula gives 24 but should be 1) or `{1,1,2}` (gives 12, but should be 6) or `{2,2}` (gives 6 but there are only 3).

Answer (score 2):

```
TakeDrop[#,1]&/@NestList[RotateLeft, {a,b,c,d},3]

(* {{{a}, {b, c, d}}, {{b}, {c, d, a}}, {{c}, {d, a, b}}, 
    {{d}, {a, b, c}}} *)
```

And

```
TakeDrop[#,2]&/@NestList[RotateLeft, {a,b,c,d},3]

( {{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{b, c}, {d, a}}, {{c, d}, {a, b}}, 
   {{d, a}, {b, c}}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't any faster than the original code, just a different approach.

```
partitionList2[list_, pat_] := Module[{rn, p},
  rn = Range@Length@pat; 
  p = Flatten[MapThread[ConstantArray, {rn, pat}]]; 
  DeleteDuplicates@
   Table[Flatten /@ Reap[MapThread[Sow, {list, q}], rn][[2]], {q, Permutations[p]}]]

AbsoluteTiming[
 a = partitionList[Range[12], {3, 1, 4, 2, 2}];]
(* {27.6628, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[
 b = partitionList2[Range[12], {3, 1, 4, 2, 2}];]
(* {27.5801, Null} *)

Sort[a] == Sort[b]
(* True *)
```